# Internal implementation of sys.platform

Tags: python, cpython

I wanted to understand how does `sys.platform` fetches the platform name i.e `linux` or `aix` and how exactly it does this differently from `platform.system()` which seems to call `os.uname()` under the hood and then normalize its output. I was going through the cpython source code on github and found the definition of `platform` attribue inside `sysmodule.c`

```
SET_SYS_FROM_STRING("platform",
                        PyUnicode_FromString(Py_GetPlatform()));
```

The function `Py_GetPlatform` is defined in `getplatform.c` like below

```
#include "Python.h"

#ifndef PLATFORM
#define PLATFORM "unknown"
#endif

const char *
Py_GetPlatform(void)
{
    return PLATFORM;
}
```

From this code it looks if the macro `PLATFORM` is defined then return it, else define `PLATFORM` and initialize it with value `unknown` before returning. I searched the entire git repo but could not any definition of this macro `PLATFORM`.

I am not very familier with C but based on my understanding i could not find its implementation, so can any one point in right direction.

Comment: `PLATFORM` is determined compile-time; to be more precise, it is `configure` that finds this out (see the `checking MACHDEP...` part) from `uname -s`

Comment: so does `sys.platform` makes call to `uname` in order to figure out its vaue ?

Comment: No, that had happened compile-time, so if you run it under WSL, it will still report the hardcoded "linux" string.

Comment: that is what I am trying to find how it determines the underlying os and sets the value of `platform` . Where in the code is this defined, i couln't find in cpython git repo.

Comment: I might have already mentioned the `configure` script. That's where it is determined.